# Cannot change styles dynamically in CFLayoutArea

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I have been writing ColdFusion/JS for 15 years, and this has me totally baffled!

I can run javascript to do anything inside my CFLayoutArea, but it will not let me display or change the styles in JS.

When you load the dashboard.cfm page in the layoutarea, it gives an javascript error anytime you try to change or reference (display) any style attribute related to the div element.

Here is the calling page:

```
function dashBoard() {
    ColdFusion.navigate('dashboard.cfm','content');
}

<cflayout>
    <cflayoutarea>
        <cfdiv id="content" />
    </cflayoutarea>
</cflayout>
```

Here is dashboard.cfm:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#szliderbar1{
    width:37%;
}
</style>
<script>
    displayProgress = function() { 
    var tttt = document.getElementById('szliderbar1');
        alert(tttt.style.width);      
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>  

    <div id="szliderbar1"> hey
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<cfset ajaxonload("displayProgress")>
```

Comment: You've been using CF/JS for 15yrs, yet you're using CFLAYOUT?? Can you provide a full-ecapsulated, stand-alone repro case that demonstrates what you're experiencing (and *only* demonstrating that: no irrelevant mark-up / CSS / JS).

Comment: Well, i'm using JQuery, Fancybox, and a lot of stuff... CFTree with cflayoutareas onClick is an extremelly efficient (fast, and powerful) way to show the content of hierarchical containers.... i have edited the code for simplicity as requested..

Comment: edited it again for more clarity

Comment: The problem can be easily fixed by NOT using `cflayout`

Comment: I couldn't agree with Scott and Adam more.  Stay away from the layout stuff in ColdFusion.  There are way better options out there.

Comment: See this blog from Ben Forta - http://forta.com/blog/index.cfm/2012/11/25/When-Using-ColdFusion-No-Longer-Makes-Sense. Make sure you read it because the title is a bit mis-leading.